# Numeric vs AlphaNumeric URL

Tags: php, apache, url

What is the difference between...

`http://mysite.com/12345`
and
`http://mysite.com/an6`

I am wondering because it would be easier to handle everything as numbers and I still see no reason to move from numbers to alpha numeric.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what the point of these URLs is. The most common reason for using a mixture of letters and numbers is that it can hold more data.

Comment: numeric urls are not SEO friendly.

Comment: @sulabh and a URL like "an6" is? How?

Comment: an6 is not SEO friendly.

Comment: www.mysite.com/new-products.html is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially in the two examples you gave there is not much difference. Other than the fact that you could include [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749722/558021) non-informative characters.  There is no (human readable) information contained within the URL's... They might hold :

- Article ID
- User ID
- Thread ID
- Error pages
- etc...

The difference comes into play when you start to embed some useful information in those URLs... Take for example the URL's on this site - specifically yours and its address -

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749505/numeric-vs-alphanumeric-url`

So what can we see from here (other than that its a Stack Overflow link and obviously the right source for getting your progrmaming questions answered ;)

1. It is a link to a question - `stackoverflow.com/questions/`
2. The question's ID is 9749505 -  `stackoverflow.com/questions/9749505`
3. We can see a preview of the title of the question `questions/9749505/numeric-vs-alphanumeric-url`

To get these "friendly URLs" one could possibly use a `.htaccess` file redirecting requests between URL's.

Here is a *simple example* of what an `.htaccess` file could accomplish :

```
RewriteCond $1 ^questions/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^questions/(.*)$ getQuestion.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Whats happening here is this - the actual URL that the user and browser sees is :
`example.com/questions/12345`
But the actual script that process the request is `getQuestion.php` and it gets passed a variable that was extracted from the original URL (specifically the number).  Then **that** script will retrieve the content and display it but the URL remains the same URL with the `/questions/12345`.

In actual fact the `getQuestion.php` file will handle all requests to questions.

So you see, there is no real difference between alphanumeric and numeric URLs - the difference is when you start embedding useful info into them making simply reading their names more informative for the user (and for you as the developer).

Comment: Now I know there is not REAL client benefit, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using letters a to z and numbers 0 to 9 in a URL is that you can have more combinations in less characters.

For example if you only have 3 characters you can use for your product ID, using 0 to 9 will give you 1000 combinations (000 through 999) which is 10^3 (10 characters which you can use - 0, 1, 2 ... 9 - raised at the power of 3, the final string's length).

But if you use 0 to 9 and a to z, you could store 36^3 unique IDs. (26 letters + 10 numbers) at the power of 3 which is 46656. If you would also make a distinction between lowercase and uppercase the total number would be (26 + 26 + 10)^3 = 238328. All that in just 3 characters.

The reason people use alphanumeric characters rather then numeric ID is that they have no SEO benefit, so it's best if their length is shortest, so that more relevant words can be included.

Other benefits are for social sites like twitter, where you have a character limit for your messaje, so using a strictly numerical ID would be inefficient.

On possible downside is that SQL queries tend to be faster when using numerical IDs rather than text ones, but there are ways to avoid that.

Comment: About comparison time, it's so low for this amount of data that is trascurable. Consider that Oracle uses alphanumeric rowid for tables. The important thing is that the  field has to be indexed.

Comment: True, that's why I said possible downside, but thanks for pointing this out.